# Mostrar dados do Banco local na tela, Ionic

Tags: javascript, sqlite, ionic

A função que faz o *select* e joga os dados para `result` é essa:

```
$scope.queryAndUpdateOverview = function(){
  f_Select("SELECT * from cadastroPessoa",[],
          function(results){       
            $scope.dados = results;   
            console.log ($scope.dados)        
          });
}
```

Após isso eu jogo os dados pra `$scope.dados` e no html uso um `ng-repeat`, porém os dados não aparecem na tela, mas no console.log eles aparecem.

Answer (score 1):

Dê uma olhada na minha resposta em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100066/8386

Vc precisa avisar ao Angular que os dados mudaram.
Isso acontece automaticamente em alguns casos pré-definidos, como quando se usa Models (o Angular seta watchers por padrão), mas não é o caso de uma consulta a banco de dados ou outra api remota.