# Data Binding não funciona após chamar função

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
$scope.calcularTotal = function(startDate, endDate){
    $scope.items = $filter('betweenDate')($scope.items, 'dataPagamento', startDate, endDate);
    console.log("testee: "+$scope.items)
    var total = 0;
    var glosa = 0;
    var lote = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
      total += (item.totalLiquido);
      glosa +=(item.totalGlosa);
      lote +=(item.totalLote);
    });
    $scope.totalLiquido = total;
    $scope.totalGlosa = glosa;
    $scope.totalLote = lote;
    console.log("Total: "+$scope.total)
    $state.go('tabs.facts', {}, {reload: true});
  }
```

Nessa função eu percorro um Array e faço a soma dos valores. No `console.log` que tem no final o total aparece corretamente. Porém quando tento fazer o Data Binding em minha página os valores não aparecem:

Essa é a página:

```
ion-view title="Totais" cache-view="false">
  <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
    <h3 style="text-align:center">Total</h3>
    <p style="margin-top:30px;font-weight:bold;color: #0066FF">Total Lote:    {{totalLote | currency}}</p>
    <p style="font-weight:bold;color: #990000">Total Glosa: {{totalGlosa | currency}}</p>
    <p style="font-weight:bold;color: #339900">Total Líquido: {{totalLiquido | currency}}</p>
  </br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<p>
  <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home" style="width:100%"> Home</a>
</p>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

E esse é o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como poderia resolver esse problema?

Comment: Vc imprimi apenas o $scope.total. Coloque os outros valores também

Comment: Coloquei e todos são impressos no console @EmirMarques. Porém eles não aparecem na página

Comment: De uma olhada: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8k3dg.png

Comment: Tente sem o filter currency

Comment: Também não funciona @EmirMarques

Comment: O estranho é que quando eu coloco esse trecho de dentro da função calcularTotais dentro de uma outra função que tenho que carrega junto com a página funciona, porém não faz o que eu quero.

Comment: Acho que o problema está ao realizar tudo isso quando clico em um botão e já mudo pra outra página. Talvez a página não esteja sendo atualizada :/

Comment: o reload : true não está forcando o recarregamento? Passe como false

Comment: Não mudou nada. Outro fato estranho, quando eu declaro as variaveis no começo da página, ex: $scope.totalLiquido = ""; aparece o valor 0 dai.

Answer (score 1):

Dicas:

1) Você tem de entender o [ciclo de digest do Angular](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=ciclo%20de%20digest%20do%20Angular&oq=ciclo%20de%20digest%20do%20Angular&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8);

2) Você deve chamar esta função em algum lugar (você não detalhou isso na pergunta) seja ao clicar um botão ou como código no controller;

3) Quando você altera variáveis do scope dentro da função, essas alterações aconteceram em um momento posterior ao digest inicial na carga do view, então você deve avisar o Angular para re-escanear as alterações. Algo como:
`if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();` na última linha da sua função.